# Python, countdown number if the guess is right?

Tags: python, while-loop, count, numbers

new in python here,
I have a code which guesses number and it works fine. but what I want to add to it is when my guess is correct count down to 0,
I have this code :

```py
num = 3
my_guess = ""

while my_guess != num:
    my_guess = int(input("enter:"))
    
print ("great job")
```

where and how to I do it (with comment line if possible please )
thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate what do you mean under *"count down to 0"*?

Comment: so as I have defined my number is 3 , so user guesses numbers till the guess is right (3), then it prints 3,2,1. I hope this explained your question.

Comment: Just make another loop iterating over some range *(e.g. `range(3, 0, -1)`)* then print current item of this range and call [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) with some delay.

Comment: thanks Oliver but I understand the Pseudocode but I am not sure where and what syntax to use in my existing code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I thought I have explained the specific? do you get to see my initial code that print the guessing number ? if so this is what I want to add additional code , 1: when my guess is right the output and result prints and show reverse number 3 , 2 ,1 , 0, is this part clear ?  I think I know what the code should do I just don't know how and where in my loop to add this performance, in some blogs they have mentioned count -=1 but I don't understand and I don't know where to add in my code and how to implementing it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this isn't too much new information at once but `import` `random` `if/else` `continue` `try/raise` and `formatted strings` are certainly worth understanding.

```
import random # random module for PRNG
num = random.randint(0,9) # get int 0<=i<=9
count_wins = 0 # start counter for wins at 0
count_losses = 0 # start counter for wins at 1

while count_wins <= 3: # while count_wins is less than 3
    try: # If an error occurs in this try block the except will be executed
        my_guess = int(input("enter:")) # cast input to int and set to my_guess
        if my_guess < 0 or my_guess > 9: # raise Value Error for ints out of range
            raise ValueError # Raise Value Error
            continue # go back to the top of the loop
    except ValueError: # specify this except block is for ValueErrors
        print("invalid input") # print invalid input
    if(my_guess == num): # if you guessed correctly
        print("great job") # print "great job"
        num = random.randint(0, 9)  # pick a new number
        count_wins += 1 # increment counter
    else: # if you guessed incorrectly
        count_losses += 1 # increment counter

print(f"Wins: {count_wins}") # print wins
print(f"Losses: {count_losses}") # print losses
```

Comment: thanks Pie, it is a very useful line of codes but it is not actually doing what I am asking .

Comment: What does "when my guess is correct count down to 0" mean? Like count from what? do you want `num-=1` instead of `num = random.randint(0,9)` perhaps?

Comment: when I run your suggestion it just goes on indefinately and it doesn't seem to have a control where to break and do what it is asked ( I want to implement a num -=1 to my code where if I enter right guess ( 3 ) it prints "well done' and contune printing 3,2,1, .

Comment: It doesn't go on indefinitely it loops until you guess correctly 3 times. (which was initially what I thought you meant by counting down... What do you mean? continue printing 3,2,1? just `[print(num-k) for k in rang(num)]` or change the number you are trying to guess?

Comment: thanks Pie, ia m not sure if you have seen my initial code or not, so far my code is working the way I want meaning , I can enter numb er till I guess the right number , what I want to add to my code is when my guess is correct to count down from 3 to 0 not guessing 3 times. thanks

Comment: Good luck have fun. I don't really have anything else to tell you...

Answer (score 0):

this is what I was looking for , in case someone else has a similar question

```
num = 3
my_guess = ""

while my_guess != num:
    my_guess = int(input("enter:"))
    
print ("great job")
while num >=0:
    print (num)
    num = num -1
```